# Magento 2.2.5 : How to place a check on prouduct page on product attributes

Tags: product-attribute, catalog-rules

How can we can place an **if condition** on proudct attibutes in a frontend .phtml file

[image]

In front end .phtml which is associated with our handle in custom module layout catalog_product_view , we get serialized_condition as

> {"type":"Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":[{"type":"Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition\Product","attribute":"category_ids","operator":"==","value":"2","is_value_processed":false}]}

How to get all attibutes and  place an **if condition** on the attributes which matches our values in db table column name serialized_conditions  like , if either the Sku ,climate,collar etc matches with the current product-  do certain operation? Even if someone can provide directions about how it is done in the core files would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use magento2 core condition validate function , try the below code in your block or wherever you need it.

```
$id = 10;
$rule = $this->rule->create()->load($id);
        if ($rule->getConditions()->validate($this->getCurrentProduct())) {
                    return true;
        }
```